# Hive Queries are running very slowly in Spark 2.0

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I have below simple HIVE Query, we have a use-case where we will run multiple HIVE queries in parallel, in our case it is 16 (num of cores in our machine, using scala PAR array). In Spark 1.6 it is executing in 10 secs but in Spark 2.0 same queries are taking 5 mins.

"select * from emp as e join dept as d on o.dept_id = t.dept_id where o.dept_id = 100”

Can someone help me what could be wrong. Why it is taking so long ?

regards, Jay

Comment: Can you confirm that the queries are executed in parallel using web UI?

Answer (score 0):

For a query that takes seconds in 1.6 to take minutes in 2.0 is usually about task errors which you can see it in the log files.  You may see something like "lost task .. in..".

So when a task is lost, runtime will try to start another executer with the same task configuration.

Other than that, Spark 2.0 must be faster.

Also can check your memory configuration for executers and the master.

Hope it helps.